# Why don't contents within a list change?

Tags: c#, game-development

I am creating a Tetris console game from scratch using C#. It works on a system of coordinates where I change the values based on what I need. A block has the char 0 and my algorithm for movement should find such characters in the coordinates, and then increment each of its y (height) values by 1, as if it was moving downwards. It removes the char from the original Y value and assigns it to the incremented one. Yet, nothing changes in the game, the object still stays at the top of the "map". What did I do wrong?

```
static List<MapNode> AutomaticMovementOfTheObject(List<MapNode> mapList)
{
    List<MapNode> positionsOfObject = mapList.Where(x => x.content == '0').ToList();
    positionsOfObject = positionsOfObject.OrderByDescending(x => x.y).ToList();

    ////DEBUG
    //foreach (MapNode node in positionsOfObject)
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine($"[{node.x},{node.y}] = {node.content}");
    //}

    for (int i = 0; i < positionsOfObject.Count; i++)
    {
        MapNode detectedNode = mapList.Find(n => n.x == positionsOfObject[i].x && n.y == positionsOfObject[i].y);

        mapList.Find(n => n.x == positionsOfObject[i].x && n.y == positionsOfObject[i].y).content = '\0';
        detectedNode.y++;
        mapList.Find(n => n.x == detectedNode.x && n.y == detectedNode.y).content = '0';
    }

    return mapList;
}
```

This thing is looped:

```
ShowMap(map, score);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
map = AutomaticMovementOfTheObject(map);
Console.Clear();
```

[image]

Comment: Have you debugged your program to see if it is the console output or update logic that that is causing your issues? How does your MapNode class look?

Comment: The MapNode class has 3 fields: int x, int y, char content. There are no problems with it, because then I wouldn't even be able to output the map at all.
I debugged the update logic and it works properly. The console output is just looping over all the MapNode objects inside a list and printing them